# Is there a difference between "Wrong or Right" and "Right or Wrong"

Tags: meaning, expressions, list-order

I was writing about the [difference between morals and ethics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/10631/what-is-the-difference-between-morals-and-ethics) when i wrote the following line

> both these terms talk about the right and wrong conduct of people
>      both these terms talk about the wrong and right conduct of people

I would think both these sentence would convey the same meaning , as it is like saying *You are fat and tall* against *You are tall and fat*.

I just need a confirmation that these two sentences convey the same meaning. Am i missing anything?

Comment: The idiom is _right or wrong_. _Wrong or right_ is simply odd, as if the speaker is trying to make a pun on the idiom; if you say or write this, people may search for a hidden meaning. That may or may not be your intention.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, *wrong and right* is equivalent to *right and wrong*, but *right and wrong* is [by far the more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=right%20and%20wrong,%20wrong%20and%20right&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,right%20and%20wrong;,c0;.t1;,wrong%20and%20right;,c0) construction, to the point where it is idiomatic, like *sweet and sour* or *bow and arrow*.

*Wrong and right* would be unusual, and if used at all, probably chosen for some literary effect or other meaning, as John Lawler notes in his comment. I might jokingly praise the *writing and reading skills* of bloggers— suggesting they start to write before they bother to read, and denying praise of their *reading and writing* skills. An old *Simpsons* line has the narrator of a video describing the [*do's and do-not-do's of foundation repair*](http://www.snpp.com/episodes/9F05.html), instead of the *do's and don'ts*, for humorous effect.

Wiktionary has a [list of "Siamese twins"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aEnglish_Siamese_twins)— a more politically correct term would be *[binomial expression](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode81/languagepoint.shtml)* or  *[irreversible binomial](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2008/04/toasty-and-toastie.html)*— which includes similar phrases which follow a conventional order, from *good and evil* to *fish and chips*.