# "pros and cons", "black and white", "ups and downs". Always in a fixed sequence, is there a word or phrase for these?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology, cliche, freezes, list-order

Is there a word or phrase for two nouns or adjectives joined by a conjunction (usually "and") in a fixed sequence?

> - alive and well
> - fast and furious
> - hat and gloves
> - pen and pencil
> - law and order
> - wit and wisdom
> - salt and pepper
> - bacon and eggs
> - horse and carriage
> - Adam and Eve
> - ladies and gentlemen
> - loud and clear
> - heads or tails
> - yes or no
> - dead or alive

Comment: great question!

Comment: An *idiomatic collocation*?

Comment: They're called ***Freezes***, because they're a special kind of frozen form. The order of the conjuncts is significant both phonetically and semantically, as it happens. Cooper and Ross discuss them in great detail in [their paper "World Order"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/worldorder.pdf). More information on the phenomenon is [available here](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a15299%20cooper%20ross).

Comment: Related: [*Which comes first: cat or dog?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32822/)

Comment: Also related: *[Is there a difference between “Wrong or Right” and “Right or Wrong”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162158)*, *[Is “forth and back” more proper than “back and forth”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76999)*, and *[“Mom and Dad” vs “Dad and Mom”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121756)*.

Comment: Cliches perhaps.

Comment: For some of these examples the reverse ordering ("eggs and bacon", "gloves and hat") is also encountered.

Comment: I would have called these a type of *[set phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phraseme)*, apparently also known as a *phraseme*.  There is no need to restrict to pairs: "sex and drugs and rock & roll" is a triplet, one of which is a pair.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, they're usually called *Irreversible Binomials* - *Binomials* for short - or *Binominals*. (Unfortunately, *Binomials* is also a mathematical term). I've read about them under the term *freezes* as used by John Lawler in the comments, but the majority of the literature and also grammar references that talk about this, that I'm aware of, use the term *Binomials*.

Binomials have two main characteristics. The first, as noted by the Original Poster, is that the order is usually perceived as fixed. The second is that the two terms are normally the same part of speech, though not always Nouns. Three of the examples in the Original Poster's list were Adjective pairings: *alive and well, fast and furious, dead or alive*. You can find verbs too:

- duck and dive
- stand and deliver
- pushing and shoving
- wait and see

and of course prepositions:

- above and beyond
- in and out
- up and down
- round and round (I'm not sure that should be in there, but it is irreversible!)

People are still writing books about them: [The (Ir)reversibility of English Binomials: Corpus, constraints, developments ...](http://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=BA1aBAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PR1&dq=binominals+grammar&ots=HIysNPNZ05&sig=hqwjjvnEY4HDAKOyU2U03ZhdW8w#v=snippet&q=trinomials&f=false)

And of course they're a hot topic for EFL students everywhere who don't want to get their forks and knives the wrong way round! [BBC Binomials](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode81/languagepoint.shtml)

Here's a Wikipedia entry that also calls them *Siamese twins* as well as *binomial pairs*: [Siamese pairs, binomials, freezes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_twins_%28linguistics%29)

Binomials occur in many languages and are often the subject of academic research. There's also trinomials of course:

- men, women and children.
- sex and drugs and rock'nroll (though that's really a 4-nomial in my opinion).
- in no way, shape or form
- blood, sweat and tears
- tall, dark and handsome
- me, myself and I

So, you've got a choice here: *Siamese pairs, freezes, irreversible binomials, binomials, binomial pairs* or *binominals*! But don't forget trinomials too.

Comment: The 'fork and knife' example reminded me of the old Monty Python sketch where an Irish diner asks of a waiter 'Where's me fork 'n knife?' and gets the unexpected reply 'beside yer forkun plate!'.

Comment: A slip (about "adjectives")  Great answer.

Comment: @user463240 Thanks! I didn't notice about the adjectives till I tried to come up with some adjective ones on my own and then saw one of them in your question :) Nice question!

Comment: Would you add the word "irreversible" before "binomials" so I can accept your answer?

Comment: I wonder if there is a quadrinomial also...

Comment: There certainly are quadrimonials, but I can't remember any.

Comment: Does *life, liberty, and the pursuit of happiness* qualifiy?

Comment: @CarSmack I think that would be a trinomial 'cos *the pursuit of happiness* would count as 1 NP ... but it's a good one!

Comment: "Blood, toils, tears and sweat" does not correspond in word order to the trinomial. Is this on purpose?

Comment: @CarSmack I don't know. It's got some good alliteration going on in the *toils tears* bit. That's quite famous now, d'you reckon that's a quadrimonial?

Comment: Imo, it doesn't meet the criteria of oft-used or well known. As for life, liberty, and the pursuit of happiness, I don't know if it's a trinomial or just a quote. Probably a quote that became a fixed trinomial (akin to life, liberty, and property?)

Comment: Araucaria, I've noticed that some binomials could theoretically be reversed (salt and pepper, pen and pencil) while others cannot (wait and see, alive and well) because of their chronology: first you wait and then you see,   you have to be alive first and then be well.

Comment: "though that's really a 4-nomial in my opinion"  Why?  What am I missing  here?

Comment: @Centaurus "Sex (1) 'n drugs (2) 'n rock (3) 'n roll (4)" [Although it's difficult to say because "rock and roll" is a compound (probably) and is itself a binomial: "Roll and rock" won't work!]

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in a comment, *collocation* is relevant (albeit less specific than *freezes*, mentioned in John Lawler's comment).  From [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/collocation) it means

> (linguistics, translation studies) A sequence of words or terms that co-occur more often than would be expected by chance (i.e., the statistically significant placement of particular words in a language). [eg]
>
> > 1968, John Rupert Firth, Frank Robert Palmer, *Selected Papers of J.R. Firth, 1952–1959*, Longmans, p 181:
> >        Collocations of a given word are statements of the habitual or customary places of that word in a collocational order but not in any other contextual order and emphatically not in grammatical order

Also relevant is *set phrase*.  From [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/set_phrase), it means “(grammar) A common expression whose wording is not subject to variation”.