# Term for words like "Hanky-Panky"

Tags: expressions, terminology, slang, reduplication

Is there a name for these kind of doubled words?

For example:

- *hanky-panky*
- *flim-flam*
- *hoity-toity*
- *boo-hoo*
- *zig-zag*

Note that some rhyme and others do not.

Comment: They're a subset of Siamese pairs, freezes, irreversible binomials, binomials, binomial pairs or binominals. See Araucaria's answer at [“pros and cons”, “black and white”, “ups and downs”. Always in a fixed sequence, is there a word or phrase for these?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198465/pros-and-cons-black-and-white-ups-and-downs-always-in-a-fixed-sequence/198474#198474). The Wikipedia article has a list of Siamese twins 'With rhymes and similar-sounding words'.

Comment: Edwin, he's not asking about any set expression that comes in pairs.

Comment: From the title on the hot question list, I expected that the answer would be `euphemisms`.  Clearly not, though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*hanky-panky* is an example of **rhyming reduplication**

*zig-zag* is an example of **ablaut reduplication**

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/reduplication

Answer (score 35):

I believe the word you're looking for is **reduplication**.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication):

> Reduplication in linguistics is a morphological process in which the root or stem of a word (or part of it) or even the whole word is repeated exactly or with a slight change.

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reduplication) gives specific types:

> - Exact type: acute-null accents; baby-talk-like
>
>   - bye-bye, choo-choo, night night, no-no, pee-pee, poo-poo, etc.
> - Ablaut type: acute-grave accents, high-low vowels, front-back vowels.
>
>   - bric-a-brac, chit-chat, criss-cross, kitty-cat, knick-knack, jibber-jabber, splish-splash, zig-zag, sing-song, etc.
> - Rhymed type: acute-acute accents, varied initials.
>
>   - claptrap, hokey-pokey, honey bunny, razzle-dazzle, slim jim, super-duper, teeny-weeny, wingding, etc.