# Is there any rule which dictates the ordering of non-proper, non-pronoun nouns in a list?

Tags: nouns, word-order, lists, rules, list-order

For example,

Is "Design, Operation, and Management," as equally good of a list as "Management, Operation, and Design?"

My colleagues and I are having a tough time reasoning why one sounds better than the other, but we agree that there is a best-sounding list.

Comment: Don't you want to decide what is the most important element and lead with that? If you described a dish, wouldn't your starting noun be the main ingredient, like buttered rice, onions, and capers? Sesame bagel, cream cheese, and tomato?

Comment: A sequential or chronological ordering makes sense, too, because it is easy for the reader to follow (+1 for @Prem).

Comment: I have just made a tag for questions about word order in lists like this; you may be interested in looking at some of the others: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-order?sort=votes&pageSize=30

Comment: @YosefBaskin , thanks , I incorporated your comment into my answer

Comment: "Design, management, and operation" is alphabetical, so *clearly* it's the proper order. (yes, I kid)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there is **no rule for ordering general lists**, we can probably consider specific cases:
(A) **cases where an ordering may be mandatory** (eg listing Royalty or Government Officials or by some sort of seniority)
(B) **cases where an ordering may be natural** (eg ordering temporally or by some measurement like size or age)
(C) **cases where phrases may have a standard ordering** (eg "Red, White, and Blue" or [Binomials](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198465/pros-and-cons-black-and-white-ups-and-downs-always-in-a-fixed-sequence) or [examples here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-order?sort=votes&pageSize=30), thanks to @Christian Bouwense & @sumelic)
(D) **cases where the writer wants to highlight the most important elements before the least important elements** (this is subjective and no rule exists)

Your example of **"Design, Operation, and Management"** is **"temporal order"**, because:
"Design" of some equipment comes first ;
"Operation" of that equipment comes next ;
"Management" of the systems using that equipment comes last, because we can talk about that only when the first two are ready.
It will probably be a title of a text book.

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of an official rule, but people usually go by what sounds aesthetically pleasing. There are some combinations that are generally laid out in a set sequence, such as

> Red, White, and Blue

if you are describing the American flag, for instance. But in the general case, it is up to you.

Comment: +1 , thanks , I have added this as case (C) in my answer.