# Why "milk and sugar", but rarely "sugar and milk"?

Tags: word-order, lists, list-order

**For example**

- "Adam and Eve" is (almost) never said as "Eve and Adam".
- Making tea: "milk or sugar", but rarely "sugar or milk".
- Elevator: "up
  or down" is more common than "down or up".

Some groupings are equally common in both orders:

- "coffee or tea" / "tea or coffee"
- "time and space" / "space and time"

Is there a word to describe this order?

Comment: You can find an answer [here!](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198465/pros-and-cons-black-and-white-ups-and-downs-always-in-a-fixed-sequence/198474#198474). They're called irreversible binomials :-)

Comment: @Araucaria, thank you for the answer! It is definitely what I was looking for (and a duplicate of the provided question you shared). I didn't use/have the correct search terms to find the results.

Comment: Yes, that's often the way :)